# Can my Yashica Super Yashicon 800mm f/8 lens be fixed?

Tags: lens, repair, equipment-damage

Probably a silly question, but I have got a '70s Super Yasinon 1:8 Yashica supertelephoto lens (I think, that is on the lens, anyway. The body has no markings except 'lens made in japan'; forgive my ignorance). The serial number on the lens is R8000088. Anyway, it was my dad's.

Unfortunately while moving last year a family member somehow dropped it from a height of at least six feet to concrete. The end ring and part of the body is dented quite badly. Is this lens dead or could it be restored?

[image: picture of lens]

Comment: Have you tried taking photos with it? It's not obvious from looking at the picture above that it's optically affected.

Answer (score 5):

Wallet width notwithstanding, just about anything can be repaired. Whether it makes economic sense is another matter.

Looking at the photo, the only apparent non-cosmetic damage is to the front clear (protective) filter and that the filter can be unscrewed. The basic repair would be to remove and discard the damaged filter.

That's not to say that there isn't mechanical damage to the focusing mechanisms or that the optical elements are not damaged. That's a matter for hands-on examination. If the damage is more extensive, it may not make economic sense to repair the lens.

The Yashica Super Yashicon 80cm f:8 lens is not particularly common but it does not appear to be highly sought after either. As best I can tell from the internet it is a [two element: one group](http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_3561.html) design and weighs about 3kg.